# Jwplayer - stop external video

Tags: jwplayer

I am using external video from Jwplayer.com. I would like to stop video after clicking on another div element. I didn't recieved any .js file or anything (i have only iframe code). Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="stop_player" style="margin-top:10px;"> div stop player</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var player = jwplayer("player");

player.setup({
  file: <media_path>,
});

$('#stop_player').on('click', function() {
  player.stop();
});
</script>
```

demo: http://codepen.io//pen/xEGapz

Comment: Where did you get that library from? I didn't find any and they didn't give me any. It tolds me "jwplayer is not defined" because I had no library

Comment: you need to add jwplayer.js (needs account) and  jquery link. You can find demos here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/

Comment: I got account but I can't find that creepy .js library :D

Comment: so after login on jwp select, on the left menu, Players -> Tools  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you register for a free account you can grab a self-hosted library from your dashboard: https://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/